Searching for: Manga about healer girl / bodyguard - Highschool
I'm searching for a manga that I started reading years ago. I think it's a shoujo, with art similar to Card Captor Sakura etc.
The girl is a healer, but she doesn't know it yet. She can heal animals/people by transferring the wounds into herself. Her mother (already deceased) was like her, that's why her father doesn't want her to know, because she will hurt herself if that means she can help others.
Her family helped raise for a boy that works kind of like a bodyguard. He knows about her powers.
She thinks he hates her because he never lets her touch him. But since he trains in martial art all the time, he doesn't want her to touch him and absorbs his wounds.
I specifically remember she heals a bird in the first chapter and gets a fever because of it.
Does anyone know?

https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/271196 - similar power, but not in a school. https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/223623 - male protagonist
